# Работа с базой данных mysql через winscp

Tags: mysql, хостинг, winscp

Загрузил на хостинг дамп базы данных mysql. Использовал эти команды:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost;
use <название базы>
source /var/www/<путь>/<название базы>.sql;
```

Никаких ошибок при загрузке не возникло, везде были warning 0.
Но на хостинге все запросы, связанные с базой, не работают. Есть подозрения, что с самой базой что-то не так, и она неправильно загрузилась. Как это проверить?

Еще такой вопрос интересует. Возможно ли как-то посмотреть на таблицу mysql прямо в хостинге через winSCP, не прибегая к консольным командам, как это можно было сделать в Open Server?